# Modify time in calendar invite email or stop calendar invite email in Microsoft Booking

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-booking

I am creating a booking through Graph API. Booking is working fine, two emails were sent, a booking confirmation, and a calendar invite.

I want to change the time in the calendar invite only, or at least want to prevent sending calendar invite emails at all.

I went through docs, but did not find any solution. [One post suggested that as of now there is no such feature that can disable email invite using Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/128774/disable-emails-to-attendees-when-creating-an-event).

Is it possible to prevent sending the calendar invite email in Microsoft Booking?

[image]